# Mysql Combining the values of multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have searched for the answer to this and cannot find it anywhere. Not quite how I want anyway.

I have five Mysql columns in a table, that I want to combine to make one column.

```
 column1value | column2value | column3value | column4value | column5value
```

Needs to become

```
column1valuecolumn2valuecolumn3valuecolumn4valuecolumn5value
```

In one column (Column 1). And I need this to happen for every row.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why couldn't use the `concat` function?

Comment: @Sebas that's the problem perhaps OP doesn't know about `concat` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to retrieve the data combined in that fashion:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         column1value,
         column2value,
         column3value,
         column4value,
         column5value
       ) column1value
FROM   my_table
```

If you want to permanently update the data in the table:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    column1value = CONCAT(
         column1value,
         column2value,
         column3value,
         column4value,
         column5value
       )
```

If you furthermore want to remove the old columns:

```
ALTER my_table
  DROP column2value,
  DROP column3value,
  DROP column4value,
  DROP column5value
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
select concat(column1value,column2value,column3value,column4value,column5value) 
  AS allvalues from table1
```

[little demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2013e/2)

to be all in column 1

```
   UPDATE my_table
  SET    column1 = CONCAT(column1value,column2value,column3value,column4value,column5value
   )
```